# Equation involving summation of logarithms

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find the largest integer $n$ that satisfies

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left \lfloor{\frac 12 +\log_{10}k}\right \rfloor \leq 1000.$$

Using wolfram.alpha, I was able to approximate a few values of $k$ and $n$. Then again, I could have solved this (painstakingly) by keeping on substituting values of $k$ and $n$. However, I want to know a way to solve this problem without the use of a calculator. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Something that may help, the function grows one every time $k\ge 10^{a+0.5}$ for $a\in\Bbb N$, e.g. for $k<10^{0.5}$ the function inside the sum is $0$, for $10^{0.5}\le k<10^{1.5}$, the function inside the sum is $1$ etc.

Comment: This is a problem from an active contest on artofproblemsolving – are you supposed to be getting help on the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd need to calculate $\sqrt{10}$ by hand, which is $\doteq 3.16227766$.

From this, we can see that the summand increases in value when $k=4, 32,$ and $317$, and that should be enough to find $n$.

For $k<4$, the summand is zero. For $4 \leq k < 32$, the summand is $1$. For For $32 \leq k < 317$, the summand is $2$. For all the values of $k \geq 317$ that we care about, it's $3$.

Up to $k=316$, the sum is $1 \cdot 28 + 2 \cdot 285 = 598$. This means we need to add no more than $(1000-598)/3 = 134$ terms, which brings us to $n = 316+134=450$.

Comment: What is the summand? It might just be another different terminology.

Comment: I thought it was just the expression you were summing, but I'll check.

Comment: So this brings us the answer $\boxed{450}$